# Flink High Availabilty not working correctly when re deploying the app with increased Task Managers

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

I am currently using `1.12.1` of **flink**

Recently, I added the HA feature using K8 in our Flink project and seeing some issue.

When we deploy the application for the first time with 2JM and 1TM it works fine. The config map in K8 gets updated with the right leader IP address.

However, if i re-deploy again with 2JM and increase TM to say 2, it doesn't work correctly. One of the TM connects to the wrong JM and stays as it is. I checked the config map and they seem to have different leader IP address. Jobmanager leader CM seems to have the right IP address however the Resource Manager CM seems to have the IP address of the standby JM.

Comment: welcome to SO..! how you have deployed the flink on K8s using helm or YAML ? how are re-deploying it ?

Comment: @HarshManvar using helm

Comment: I disabled the rolling update during deployment which fixed the issue of having different IP address in the config map for Flink HA. However, still seeing the above issue of only one TM working.

Comment: can you please share the link to the helm chart you are referring?